# Know Your Site Monday: Who are the most generous users?

Tags: discussion, trivia

Welcome to 'Know Your Site' a (hopefully) every Monday Worldbuilding trivia  feature where I use the Stack Exchange Data Explorer and maybe some python parsing to find out interesting things about the site.

I will post a question on Monday, and people have until Thursday at noon to guess the answer! To be clear, using the Data Explorer to get the answer is cheating. If you use that to find the answer, feel good about your inherent superiority, but don't post it! Also, absolutely do not look at my Data Explorer profile, because that is definitely cheating.

**Which users have posted the most total value of bounties on Worldbuilding?**

Name the top three in order to win!

Side note: If you have any good ideas about awards for the winner, please post to comments.

Comment: The normal award would probably be a small bounty on the newest question or something like that - but being awesome and getting everything right should be reward enough already ;)  (Very cool idea by the way, looking forward to some site trivia)

Comment: Just to be clear, this is all-time bounties, right - rather than just, say, 2017?

Comment: @HDE226868 This is all time

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. [dot_Sp0T](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2746/dot-sp0t)
2. [HDE 226868](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/627/hde-226868)
3. [Allmighty @James, Steward of WB, Crusher of Dreams, Lord of The Factory Floor and diamond moderator of WorldBuilding, Snorter of Beverages, First of his name.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/189/james)

Comment: Correct names, wrong order!

Comment: @kingledion Yeah, getting the correct order of James many names is hard...

Comment: Finally I made it onto a list!

Comment: @dot_Sp0T And in my version you are even in the first place! Congrats on fooling me like that ;)

Comment: Thank you for properly addressing me, you shall be blessed and I will offer to smite one person of your choosing in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I marked Secespitus as correct, since he basically was. I won't ask any more questions demanding a correct order.

The correct order is

```
HDE 226868  2700
James       2150
dot_Spot    1400
```

The rest of the top 10, for those interested, is

```
Samuel     1200
JBH        1150
JDlugosz   1100
TrEs-2b    1100
Jim2B       950
Secespitus  900
Will        800
```